# London Airport strikes from November 18 to November 21 2022

Tags: airports, london, lhr

Would you be able to advise which flights are likely to be affected by the strike at London Airport.

Does it affect only LHR Airport or does it affect LGW Airport as well?

I have a ticket to travel from New York to LHR on 18th November through British Airways. Can anyone advise whether I should change the ticket in advance or book another flight to LGW?

Comment: From the news, it only affects Heathrow. Let others who has direct knowledge reply.

Answer (score 6):

According to https://www.passengerterminaltoday.com/news/london-heathrow-airport-workers-strike-over-pay.html:

> Workers employed by Dnata and Menzies at London **Heathrow** Airport will take three days of strike action, beginning November 18, 2022, in a dispute over pay.
>
> The strike action involves 700 workers employed by Dnata and Menzies. The workforce carries out a wide variety of roles, including ground-handling, airside transport and cargo. The strike action will begin in the early hours of November 18 and will be completed in the early hours of November 21. It will lead to disruption, cancellations and delays at **terminals 2, 3 and 4**. The strike action is expected to particularly affect **Qatar Airways**, which has scheduled an additional 10 flights a week during the World Cup. **Other airlines that will be hit heavily by the strike action include Virgin Atlantic, Singapore Airlines, Cathay-Pacific and Emirates**. Passengers returning to the US for the Thanksgiving holiday are also set to be adversely affected.

(emphasis mine)

British Airways should not be affected (in this instance!), they use Terminal 5, and I believe they have their own ground handling operations there.